# logo and h1 heading appear on same line using html and css

Tags: html, css, heading

I want to create a webpage but encountered a problem in making the logo appear near the heading. I have tried the following code but this does not produce expected results.

I have the following code:

```css
.line .box .header img {
  float: left;
}

.line .box.header h1 {
  position: relative;
  top: 1px;
  left: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div class="line">
   <div class="box">
      <div class="s-6 l-2"> 
         <div class="header">
             <img src="img/hrcimg.jpg" alt="logo">
             <h1>United Nations Human Rights Council</h1>
        </div>
      </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

WEBSITE SCREEN
[image: output seen]

Comment: What about display:inline?

Comment: Tried. Does not work.

Comment: try putting logo inside the h1 tag <h1><img src="img/hrcimg.jpg" alt="logo"></h1>

Comment: It seems to work ok on CodePen http://codepen.io/anon/pen/VjYNXQ

Comment: @arun Does not work.

Comment: Also seems to work in [JS Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/846gpLhx/); so you need to work out what's different in your code. I'd suggest adding your CSS and gradually adding back ancestor elements to your HTML until you see the design break.

Comment: I'd imagine you've got another style elsewhere that is overriding what you're trying to do here as it works fine for me.

Comment: I also try your code, its working as you desired.

Comment: @Sahitya,scott both methods are working, the image size needs adjustments, and positioning also needed

Comment: Why does that column look so small? If the text is wrapping like that there's no room left for it to sit right of the image.
Hard to really troubleshoot the problem without a live example to refer to. Consider creating a pen you can link to, with the relevant styles and/or frameworks included so we have a better prospective of the whole picture.

Comment: The entire code is here http://codepen.io/anon/pen/gMbyjQ

Comment: as @UncaughtTypeError specified above, you do have that column too small to fit (*hint: remove class l-2), if you actually need it to be that small, might as well consider another layout or throw some `position: absolute`

Comment: There's more to this than just the h1 and the image. One of the parent elements may have a fixed width that's forcing the two in a column. My suspect is .s-6.l-2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to increase the width of `.l-2` element.

Setting this element's width to 100% will result in the layout the title of your question eludes to.

When reaching lower resolutions, you'll need to adjust these styles accordingly so that the structure is maintained to a point.
Once the resolution reaches mobile proportions, consider displaying them in their own lines. This can be done by setting the logo to display as `block` with `width: 100%;` & `height: auto;`, you'll also need to kill the `float` rule at this point.

Answer (score 1):

Try this out:

```css
img, h1 {
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
```

```html
<header>
  <img src="http://placehold.it/100x100">
  <h1>COMPANY NAME</h1>
</header>
```

Answer (score 0):

So i made a little something, correct me if i am wrong where the logo needs to be :)

```
.line img {
  float: left;
}

.line h1 {
  position:relative;
  float:left;
  top: 1px;
  left: 10px;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/3an65dfp/3/